# Can a JavaFX TableColumn's header text be made to bleed over to another column?

Tags: css, layout, javafx

I have a TableView with two TableColumns. On the left is a wide column that needs to be able to show entries up to 30 characters. On the right is a narrow column that needs to be able to show just one character. But the title of the right column needs to be a long word (it is required). But I don't have the luxury in terms of space to have a column as fat as the required header text. If I make the right column as wide as its header text, the data in the left column gets truncated. I would like the header text of the column on the right to bleed over into the column on the left (there is no worry of it running into the left column's header text). Is this possible by setting some fx css of my TableView and/or one or both of the TableColumns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example where the column header "Long Last Name" bleeds into the column header to the left of it.

[image: bleed]

*bleed.css*

```
.column-header.left-header > .label {
    -fx-alignment: baseline-left;
}

.column-header.bleed-header > .label {
    -fx-alignment: baseline-right;
    -fx-padding: 0 3 0 0;
}
```

*Code snippet which enables the "bleed"*

```
TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>();
lastNameCol.setMinWidth(80);
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
lastNameCol.getStyleClass().add("bleed-header");

Label headerLabel = new Label("Long Last Name");
headerLabel.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
lastNameCol.setGraphic(headerLabel);
```

The solution required a bit of trickery:

1. Use of css to set alignment properties.
2. Use a label graphic for the header.

Supplying the label graphic gives you direct control of the minimum width (to prevent the default behaviour of the header label being elided when it is too long).

*Executable code sample*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewHeaderBleed extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");

        table.setPrefHeight(200);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.getStyleClass().add("left-header");

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>();
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(80);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.getStyleClass().add("bleed-header");

        Label headerLabel = new Label("Long Last Name");
        headerLabel.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        lastNameCol.setGraphic(headerLabel);

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(100);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("bleed.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
   }
}
```